# Is "any" singular or plural

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

If I see any merchandise out of place, I fix **it**.

or should it be ...I fix them.

Comment: _Merchandise_ is a singular mass noun, so it should be _it_. As for _any_, it can modify either singular or plural, and can refer to either when alone.

Answer (score 1):

"Any" is just a modifier for this purpose - the number of the noun it modifies is unchanged:

> If I see *any merchandise* out of place, I'll fix *it*.  **(mass noun)**

> If I see *any item* out of place, I'll fix *it*.  **(singular noun)**

> If I see *any items* out of place, I'll fix *them*.  **(plural noun)**

Answer (score 0):

"Any" is neither singular nor plural - it means "one or more [optionally: of the following] things."

> Any car that hits that pothole will suffer tire damage.

or

> Any moths that see the light are irresistibly drawn to it.

But "merchandise" (in your example) is singular.